# is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to [RedisURI [host='192.168.129.XXX', port=7010], RedisURI [

Tags: spring-boot, connection, redis-cluster

I'm connecting to a redis 7.0.8 cluster in springboot version 2.2.9.RELEASE, which is deployed on my local virtual machine CentOS7, but it keeps reporting an error:

```
2023-03-01 20:09:31.523 ERROR 32280 --- [nio-9913-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.redis.RedisConnectionFailureException: Redis connection failed; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to [RedisURI [host='192.168.129.XXX', port=7010], RedisURI [host='192.168.129.XXX', port=7020], RedisURI [host='192.168.129.XXX', port=7030], RedisURI [host='192.168.129.XXX', port=7011], RedisURI [host='192.168.129.XXX', port=7021], RedisURI [host='192.168.129.XXX', port=7031]]] with root cause

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:148) ~[na:1.8.0_151-1-redhat]
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108) ~[na:1.8.0_151-1-redhat]
    at io.lettuce.core.output.ArrayOutput.set(ArrayOutput.java:54) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.safeSet(RedisStateMachine.java:358) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.RedisStateMachine.decode(RedisStateMachine.java:139) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:716) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode0(CommandHandler.java:680) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:675) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.decode(CommandHandler.java:596) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.lettuce.core.protocol.CommandHandler.channelRead(CommandHandler.java:565) ~[lettuce-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[netty-transport-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) ~[netty-common-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.51.Final.jar:4.1.51.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_151-1-redhat]
```

I've tried using the same version of redis to deploy a standalone redis on my VM, using springboot it is possible to connect and use it, not sure why the cluster doesn't work, is it a version incompatibility? I don't have a firewall on my virtual machine, the host and virtual machine network interoperability.

On the VM, my redis cluster is available:

```bash
[root@localhost ~]# redis-cli -c -p 7010
127.0.0.1:7010> get boo
-> Redirected to slot [13142] located at 192.168.129.XXX:7030
"for"
192.168.129.XXX:7030> set hello world
-> Redirected to slot [866] located at 192.168.129.XXX:7010
OK
192.168.129.XXX:7010> get hello
"world"
192.168.129.XXX:7010>
```

This is my springboot configuration：

```java
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.redis.cluster")
public class ClusterConfigurationProperties {
    List<String> nodes;
    public List<String> getNodes() {
        return nodes;
    }
    public void setNodes(List<String> nodes) {
        this.nodes = nodes;
    }
}


@Configuration
public class RedisClusterConfig {

    @Autowired
    ClusterConfigurationProperties clusterProperties;

    @Bean
    public RedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        return new LettuceConnectionFactory(
                new RedisClusterConfiguration(clusterProperties.getNodes()));
    }

    @Bean
    public RedisTemplate<String, byte[]> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory) {
        RedisTemplate<String, byte[]> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
        template.setConnectionFactory(redisConnectionFactory);
        return template;
    }
}
```

application.properties：

```
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[0]=192.168.129.XXX:7010
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[1]=192.168.129.XXX:7020
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[2]=192.168.129.XXX:7030
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[3]=192.168.129.XXX:7011
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[4]=192.168.129.XXX:7021
spring.redis.cluster.nodes[5]=192.168.129.XXX:7031
spring.redis.password=
spring.redis.cluster.max-redirects=3
spring.redis.timeout=60000ms
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-active=32
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-wait=-1ms
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.max-idle=16
spring.redis.lettuce.pool.min-idle=8
```

This is my redis.conf：

```bash
port 7010
cluster-enabled yes
cluster-config-file nodes-7010.conf
cluster-node-timeout 5000
appendonly yes
daemonize yes
#requirepass redis-123456
loglevel warning
logfile /root/Tools/redis-cluster/7010/redis_7010.log
#bind 0.0.0.0
protected-mode no
```

I referred to your recommended tutorial (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#cluster), still the same error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same problem with Redis 7.0.10 and Spring Boot 2.1.6.RELEASE. It seems that upgrading the Spring Boot version can fix it. I tried versions 2.3.12.RELEASE and 2.7.9, and both worked.

Comment: Not able to see any link between above error and this solution. But was facing same issue since morning and upgrading springboot did the trick, thanks a lot.